# While using ngFor - when removing item from array all directives on nested layout throw error

Tags: angular, ngfor

My templates iterates through groups and renders some nested elements, lists e.t.c.:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let group of groups">
...
    <ul class="list_devices">
        <li class="row list_devices_header" *ngIf="getNumberOfDevicesInGroup(group.id) > 0">
                                ...
        </li>
        <li class="row" *ngFor="let item of devices | matchesGroup:group.id">
                     ...
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Problem is, that when I remove a group from array:

```
delete this.groups[index]
```

rendered layout is still there and errows are thrown:

```
DeviceListComponent.html:122 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

for nested directives, which use already deleted object.

Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way.
I want to delete a group and have all nested elements be gone.
How would I do that the right way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `delete this.groups[index]` you could just use `splice`

Try this `this.groups.splice(index, 1)`

For the difference, check this question out
[Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)