# Difference in browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I'm learning `Javascript ECMA6`, but I have a problem, I trying a example from my book and results in Chrome and Safari not equal, my question is my question is whether this will affect developments in the future.

```
var pizzas = ["Margherita", "Mushroom", "Spinach & Rocket", "Pineapple & Sweetcorn"];
delete pizzas[2]

**Safari**
pizzas; //["Margherita", "Mushroom", 3: "Pineapple & Sweetcorn"]

**Chrome**
pizzas; //(4) ["Margherita", "Mushroom", empty, "Pineapple & Sweetcorn"] 0 : "Margherita" 1 : "Mushroom" 3 : "Pineapple & Sweetcorn" 
length : 4
```

Version Javascript in Chrome : 6.3.292.46

In Chrome I see empty value in 2 position in Chrome and Safari show a '3' in the next value to detele, this is really important to develop in Javascript?

I think that in Firefox is the same result (other result).

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` should not be used on arrays. It does not change array length or re-index the array.

Instead use [`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
pizzas.splice(2,1)
```

will remove 1 element starting at index=2 and reduce the length of the array by one also

See:  [Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)

Comment: Perfect! but What is the real purpose to use delete (in my book the authors use this to Removing Values from Arrays)

Comment: That sounds like a scary book. Or possibly very very old. Or you have taken it out of context and they are deleting properties of objects in arrays

Comment: The book is Novice to Ninja Javascript, do you have a book most updated?

Comment: Not me. I've never read a programming book in my life to be honest

Comment: But do you have somewhere where I can find good documentation about Javascript and guide me about it? Thanks bro!

Comment: MDN Docs as per the link I used for `splice()` above