# pop() / shift() method which returns original array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've read that `pop()/shift()` is significantly more performant than using `slice()`. https://jsperf.com/pop-vs-slice/5

Here's my use case using slice():

```
proto.wrapErrorFirst = proto.wrapErrFirst = function (fn: Function) {
  const self = this;
  return function (err: IPseudoError) {
    if (err) {
      return self.__handle(err, false);
    }
    try {
      // remove the error-first argument
      return fn.apply(this, Array.from(arguments).slice(1));
    }
    catch (err) {
      return self.__handle(err, false);
    }
  }
};
```

so this should be more performant:

```
  proto.wrapErrorFirst = proto.wrapErrFirst = function (fn: Function) {
      const self = this;
      return function (err: IPseudoError) {
        if (err) {
          return self.__handle(err, false);
        }
        try {
          const args = Array.from(arguments);
          args.shift()
          return fn.apply(this, args);
        }
        catch (err) {
          return self.__handle(err, false);
        }
      }
    };
```

but I am wondering if there is a way to do that with less code and perhaps a way to do that without having to call Array.from(arguments)?

maybe something kinda **crazy** like this:

```
delete arguments[0];
return fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: yeah I don't think that last idea (using `delete`) is going to work

Comment: Could you use a rest parameter instead? `function (err: IPseudoError, ...args) {`

Comment: @4castle my question is not that clear, but I am looking for the most performant way to shift off the first argument from the arguments "array" and then apply arguments to another function

Comment: I got that. I was just suggesting that if you declare the function differently, there would be no need to mess with `arguments`. `args` would be the array you need.

Comment: yeah, I have been there before, see this issue :) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20261

Comment: TypeScript can make it less verbose but not more performant

Comment: shift is the fast way you can use splice or slice, but shift is faster at lest in chrome, delete is not proper for remove elements of an array [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)

Comment: @AlexanderMills if you would repeat this operation thousands of time per sec I would understand the urge to improve performance but in your case it looks like an overkill to look for [optimizations](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: yeah this question is about both saving lines of code and optimizing performance - it's not just about my use case, but other people's as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create new array from arguments any way, but also you want to skip first element.
Most efficient way to do it in your case is using `slice` method from `Array.prototype` on `arguments`. So you do not need create temporary array as in first case and then slice it, and you do not need remove first element as in second case.

```
proto.wrapErrorFirst = proto.wrapErrFirst = function (fn: Function) {
  const self = this;
  return function (err: IPseudoError) {
    if (err) {
      return self.__handle(err, false);
    }
    try {
      const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      return fn.apply(this, args);
    }
    catch (err) {
      return self.__handle(err, false);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Pop/Shift is the fast way you can use splice or slice, but pop/shift is faster at lest in chrome, delete is not proper for remove elements of an array [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice).

Comment: Actually the benchmark in the question shows that `pop` is the fastest.

Comment: yeah but I need `shift()` not `pop()` when it comes down to it