# How to delete an array in an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to delete an array in an object in Javascript?
For example I want to delete:

```
RandomObject.array = [];
```

So that when I use RandomObject in ways such as copying it into another object, the array is not included.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator:

```
delete RandomObject.array;
```

**Snippet Demo to show how it works:**

```js
var RandomObject = {};
RandomObject.array = [];
console.log(RandomObject);
delete RandomObject.array;
console.log(RandomObject);
```