# Delete item from local JSON file - JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

The JSON file contains the following:

```
{
  "pets": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Hanna",
      "speciesId": 2,
      "sex": "f",
      "age": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Chris",
      "speciesId": 1,
      "sex": "m",
      "age": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's where I get the JSON data and then stringify and set into sessionStorage.

```
$.getJSON("/src/data/pets.json", function(json) {
  let petsData = JSON.stringify(json);

  window.sessionStorage.setItem("json", petsData);
});
```

I then get it and parse it back into JSON for use throughout application.

```
let theDataStr = window.sessionStorage.getItem("json");
let theData = JSON.parse(theDataStr);
```

I want to delete the entire item that contains the valued 'Hanna' and have tried the following:

```
  let PetToDelete = document.getElementById("PetNames").value // This will be the 'Hanna';
  for (let index = 0; index < theData.pets.length; index++) {
    console.log(theData.pets[index]);
    if (PetToDelete == theData.pets[index].name) {
      delete theData.pets[index];

      let petsData = JSON.stringify(theData);

      window.sessionStorage.setItem("json", petsData);
    }
  }
```

This works fine until I look back at the Session Storage and I get this:

[image: Image of JSON in Web Inspector]

Why is the item retaining the 0 index and is now null?

Furthermore, when I then try to use that data, I get the following JS Console Error because speciesId doesn't exist for that item anymore:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speciesId' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

Edit: Using Splice:

```
  var newData = theData.pets[index];

  newData.splice(index, 1);

  let petsData = JSON.stringify(newData);

  window.sessionStorage.setItem("json", petsData);
```

returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: newData.splice is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>
```

Comment: The fact that you start with JSON is completely 100% irrelevant.  JSON is just a serialization format for moving data between systems.  Don't try to manipulate JSON itself.

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/500617/5927361

Comment: "pets" is an array, not an object. Try `x=[1,2,3,4]; delete x[2]`. What is the result you expect? Should there be a gap in the array (what you're observing) or should the elements after `2` be shifted down?

Comment: @mpen I'd want the results to be shifted down as if '2' never existed, so [1, 3, 4]

Comment: @JamieBohanna — See the duplicate

Comment: Re edit: Look at the duplicate more carefully. Think about the difference between the array you want to delete something from and the thing you want to delete from it.

Comment: @Quentin - Just figured out what I was doing thanks to your comment. Thank you! <3