# Splice() deletes wrong element in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is when I'm deleting inputs that added dynamically it delete's wrong input. I reproduced my code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/armakarma/qwg3j2fa/24/ . Try to add five more inputs, type something in each input and try to delete second input. It will delete last one. Where I'm doing mistake?

```
addNewInputs() {

    let newInputValues = {
        datetime: "10.05.2019 14:00",
        position_id: 1,
        contact: "",
        address_id: "",
        new_address: "",

    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        arrayOfAddresses: [...prevState.arrayOfAddresses, newInputValues],
    }))
}

deleteInput(idx) {

    let tempObj = this.state.arrayOfAddresses

    tempObj.splice(idx, 1)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        arrayOfAddresses: tempObj,
    }))

}

onChooseAddress(e, idx) {
    console.log(e.target.value)

}

render() {

    return ( <
        div > {
            this.state.arrayOfAddresses.map((item, idx) => {
                return (
                    <div key = {idx} >
                      <input name = "contact"
                      onChange = {(e) => this.onChooseAddress(e)}
                    /> 
                      <button onClick = {() => this.deleteInput(idx)} > x < /button> 
                    </div>
                )
            })
        } 
          <button onClick = {() => this.addNewInputs()} > Add new input < /button> 
        /div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable React Stack Snippet on Stack overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537)

Comment: arrName.splice(starting index,number of element you want to delete);


Ex: arrName.splice(1,1);

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice/51090038#51090038

Comment: @SrikrushnaPal OP is not asking for correct usage of `.splice()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `chooseAddress` method, you're not passing the index from the `onChange` callback, that's why the state is not updating, and also you have not added `value` prop to the input, that's why rendering was wrong, because of input's internal state

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    adresses:[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "address": "address 1",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "address": "address 2",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "address": "address 3",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "address": "address 4",
  }
],
        arrayOfAddresses: [
        {
          datetime: "10.05.2019 14:00",
          position_id: 1,
          contact: "",
          address_id: "",
          new_address: "",
        },
      ],

    }
  }

  addNewInputs() {

    let newInputValues = {
      datetime: "10.05.2019 14:00",
      position_id: 1,
      contact: "",
      address_id: "",
      new_address:"",

    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      arrayOfAddresses: [...prevState.arrayOfAddresses, newInputValues],
    }))
  }

deleteInput(idx) {

  this.setState(prevState => {
    let tempObj = [...prevState.arrayOfAddresses]
    tempObj.splice(idx, 1)
    console.log(tempObj) 
    return {
      arrayOfAddresses: tempObj,
    }
  })

}

onChooseAddress(e, idx) {
const {value} = e.target;
    this.setState(state=>{
    let tempObj = [...this.state.arrayOfAddresses]
    tempObj[idx].new_address = value
      return {
          arrayOfAddresses: tempObj,
      }
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.arrayOfAddresses.map((item,idx)=>
    <div>

          <input
            name="contact"
            value={item.new_address}
            onChange={(e) => this.onChooseAddress(e, idx)}
          />
          <button onClick={() => this.deleteInput(idx)}> x</button>
    </div>
        )}
        <button  onClick={() => this.addNewInputs()}> Add new input </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: Same thing. Try add 5 inputs , in each input type different value to see differences. And delete second input, It will delete last one

Comment: Let me know, if you've checked it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192829/discussion-between-shridhar-sharma-and-yerlan-yeszhanov).

Comment: Have you checked?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to change:

1. Set the `value` of `<input>`. The problem is that the `arrayOfAddresses` is set correctly, but correct values are not reflected in the input.
2. Add the corresponding `idx` value to the `onChange` of `<input>`

Here's the relevant code change:

```
<input name="contact" value={item.new_address} onChange={(e) => this.onChooseAddress(e, idx)}
 />
```

Here's the fiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khqd9efv/1/)