# Unable to delete an array index/item using delete

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using `delete` in order to try to delete an item on an array;

```
const handleRowDeletion = index => {
    const inputsAdded = shareStructureInputs;
    const inputs = startupFourthStepForm.shares_estructure;

    delete inputs[index];
    delete inputsAdded[index];
}
```

I can see the first array `inputsAdded` getting deleted at the proper index but not the second one `inputs`.

This is what `inputsAdded` returns:

```
[
  "share-structure-input-0",
  "share-structure-input-1",
  "share-structure-input-2"
]
```

And `inputs`:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Name 1",
    "percentage": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Name 2",
    "percentage": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Name 3",
    "percentage": 80
  }
]
```

And I call the function on a `map`

```
                <Button onClick={() => handleRowDeletion(index)}>
                  - Delete Row
                </Button>
```

Comment: isn't `delete` only used for objects? you're not using `delete` on any object properties

Comment: Theres's a better duplicate which exactly answers your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice