# Javascript Avoid getting null after deleting objects from array

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array with multiple nested arrays. Each nested array has three objects. I am trying to delete the second one but at the moment, I am getting a null value in its place. All I want is the final output (after) to have no null values. **Splice is returning an error that the splice function doesn't exist.**

```js
var json_data=[[{value:"value1",formattedValue:"value1"},{value:"Unwanted part 3",formattedValue:"Unwanted part 3"},{value:2831.8,formattedValue:"283,180.00 %"}],[{value:"value1",formattedValue:"value1"},{value:"Unwanted part 2",formattedValue:"Unwanted part 2"},{value:349.1111111111111,formattedValue:"34,911.11 %"}],[{value:"value2",formattedValue:"value2"},{value:"Unwanted part 1",formattedValue:"Unwanted part 1"},{value:3.3703703703703702,formattedValue:"337.04 %"}]];

document.getElementById("before").innerHTML= JSON.stringify(json_data); 

for(i=0;i<json_data.length;i++){
  let items = json_data[i];
  const subItemToBeRemovedId = 1;
  items.forEach((item) => items.forEach((subItem, index) => {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(items[subItemToBeRemovedId]));
      delete items[subItemToBeRemovedId];
      //return item.subItemToBeRemovedId.splice(index, 1);
  }));
}

document.getElementById("after").innerHTML= JSON.stringify(json_data);
```

```html
<h1>before</h1>
<div id="before"></div>
<h1>after </h1>
<div id="after"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use .splice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate details why `delete` is not working, and why `splice` will.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried splice. My code has it commented out as it didn't work.

Comment: `Splice() ` is working perfect , have a look at my answer . @ApoloRadomer

Comment: `splice` works fine if you use it on an array. `item.subItemToBeRemovedId` is undefined. If `items` is the array you wish to remove the item from, use `items.splice`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code, 
Here you can simply use the `.splice()` which will remove element from your array. Don't need to use multiple `forEach()`.

```js
var json_data = [
  [{
    value: "value1",
    formattedValue: "value1"
  }, {
    value: "Unwanted part 3",
    formattedValue: "Unwanted part 3"
  }, {
    value: 2831.8,
    formattedValue: "283,180.00 %"
  }],
  [{
    value: "value1",
    formattedValue: "value1"
  }, {
    value: "Unwanted part 2",
    formattedValue: "Unwanted part 2"
  }, {
    value: 349.1111111111111,
    formattedValue: "34,911.11 %"
  }],
  [{
    value: "value2",
    formattedValue: "value2"
  }, {
    value: "Unwanted part 1",
    formattedValue: "Unwanted part 1"
  }, {
    value: 3.3703703703703702,
    formattedValue: "337.04 %"
  }]
];

document.getElementById("before").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json_data);

for (i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) {
  let items = json_data[i];
  console.log("ITEMS  ===>", items);
  items.splice(1, 1);
}

document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json_data);
```

```html
<h1>before</h1>
<div id="before"></div>
<h1>after </h1>
<div id="after"></div>
```

This is the solution you are looking for .

Comment: Answers which explain their code are upvoted more often, and downvoted less often than those which simply give the answer in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to get a hold of the inner array and then filter it based on the position:

```js
const json_data=[[{value:"value1",formattedValue:"value1"},{value:"Unwanted part 3",formattedValue:"Unwanted part 3"},{value:2831.8,formattedValue:"283,180.00 %"}],[{value:"value1",formattedValue:"value1"},{value:"Unwanted part 2",formattedValue:"Unwanted part 2"},{value:349.1111111111111,formattedValue:"34,911.11 %"}],[{value:"value2",formattedValue:"value2"},{value:"Unwanted part 1",formattedValue:"Unwanted part 1"},{value:3.3703703703703702,formattedValue:"337.04 %"}]];

document.getElementById("before").innerHTML= JSON.stringify(json_data); 

const after_json_data = json_data.map(items => 
                            items.filter((item, idx) => idx !== 1))


document.getElementById("after").innerHTML= JSON.stringify(after_json_data);
```

```html
<h1>before</h1>
<div id="before"></div>
<h1>after </h1>
<div id="after"></div>
```

Deleting array elements using the `delete` operator does not alter the `length` of the array, instead it leaves `undefined` in place of the deleted element.

For an experiment lets delete the second element from the below array:

```js
const arr = ["foo", "baz", "bar"];
delete arr[1];
console.log(arr);
```

The index `1` becomes `undefined`. But you see `null` appearing in your output instead of `undefined` this is because when you convert the array object to JSON, the `undefined` gets converted to `null` as there is no `undefined` in the JSON spec:

```js
const arr = ["foo", "baz", "bar"];
delete arr[1];
console.log(arr);
// undefined is null in the JSON string
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

delete won't do what you want it to in this case, it will always replace an array entry with an empty position as I believe it handles the Array like an object (so your length property won't update either).

You nearly have it in your commented out section I believe. Instead of:

```
 return item.subItemToBeRemovedId.splice(index, 1);
```

use:

```
items.splice(subItemToBeRemovedId, 1);
return items;
```

Splice will mutate your Array, which you can then return.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `splice` inside the callback function:

```
json_data = json_data.map(subArr => {
    subArr.splice(1,1);
    return subArr
})
```

Comment: `.map()` function doest return the object . You should use the `.filter()` instead

Comment: And who told you that he needs an object?

Comment: Here  you wrote `return` therefore i am just correcting you  @Daniyal