# How to remove an element from JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript

I want to delete values inside an array, but my code below doesn't work:

```
stations=['stations1','stations2']
 wayPoints=[{location: "stations1"},{location: "stations2"},{location: "stations3"},{location: "stations4"}]
deletStations(){

let result=[];

this.stations.forEach(index1 => rest.push(this.arrayRemove(this.wayPoints,index1)) );

}

arrayRemove(arr, value) {

 return arr.filter(function(ele){
     return ele != value;
 });

}
```

This code above doesn't remove the `{location: "stations1"}, {location: "stations2"}` from wayPoints, any suggestions please?

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` doesn't mutate the input array, it returns a new array. It will not overwrite `wayPoints` unless you manually set the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)

Comment: @Wendelin I tried that, it doesnt work either

Comment: nbokmans is there a solution to overwrite waypoints

Comment: @Javauser manually assign the result of the `arrayRemove` call to `waypoints`.

Comment: the problem is in the result of arrayRemove, it doesnt return the correcte values

Comment: `arrayRemove` is testing for reference equality (`ele != value`)  You need to check whether the property matches (`ele.location != 'value'`).  But as the answer from sebaLinares show, there are better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
const secondWayOfDoingIt = wayPoints.filter(
  element => !stations.includes(element.location)
);
```

And the same but with destructured argument:

```
const firstWayOfDoingIt = wayPoints.filter(
  ({ location }) => !stations.includes(location)
);
```

Hope it helps.