# Javascript delete object items leaves null traces

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object from a Youtube api call, let's call it `myObj` I do a for loop and delete items I don't like with:

```
delete myObj.items[i]
```

the problem is it leaves "null" traces of items deleted this way, when i then log myObj again using `JSON.stringify` it looks like this:

```
myObj now is: {"kind":"youtube#SubscriptionListResponse","etag":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","pageInfo":
{"totalResults":14,"resultsPerPage":30},"items":
[{"kind":"youtube#subscription","etag":"xxxxxx","id":"xxxxxxxxxx","snippet":{"publishedAt":"2020-12-
17T18:01:20.892352Z","title":"A Channel","description":"","resourceId":
{"kind":"youtube#channel","channelId":"xxxxx"},"channelId":"xxxxxx","thumbnails":{"default":
{"url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"medium":{"url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"high":
{"url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}},"contentDetails":{"totalItemCount":17,"newItemCount":0,"activityType":"all"}}
,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}
```

it works since it only keeps the "A Channel" item which is correct, but all the other *items* turn into `null`, and it's a problem for something like `myObj.length` later on.

I've read other threads about the issue, but they either reccomends using `delete`, which clearly doesn't work for my case, or `splice` (which doesn't work on my object from my understanding)

Comment: Instead of changing the object, you could treat it like an immutable object and create a new object with or without the properties wanted/unwanted. This would also help, keeping a more functional approach.

Comment: "*`splice` (which doesn't work on my object from my understanding)*" but you are manipulating the **array** which is at the property `items`. You can use `splice` on it.

Comment: i tried with myObj.items[i].splice(i,1) but it says splice is not a function

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: @m4tt `myOb.items.splice(i, 1)`

Comment: @m4tt you should be calling `.splice` on the *array*, not on an item in the array.

Comment: If you just need to remove the nulls, could filter this out: myObj.items.filter(item => item);

Comment: thank you, i followed that first link and changed the loop to work in reverse, then using items.split instead of items[i] worked. btw i don't know who closed with duplicate, but that link doesn't mention to use reverse loop anywhere, so is not the solution for my case at all, maybe the first link pointed out by Nikhil is