# Expected an element called undefined but got empty | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a simple array where I have a few elements.

After deleting an element, I noticed that it **outputted** **"empty"** but I was **expecting** an **undefined datatype**.

- I ran the same code on **MDN** and got an **undefined** as a result.
- I ran the code in different browsers but got **"empty"** as a result.

**When I looked for the type of this element it gave me an undefined as a result.**

I was wondering why I got 2 different terms for something where the types are the same?

Thank you in advance!

Culhaci Lucas - JeWelCrax

```
    // code
    const pizzas = ["Margherita", "Mushroom", "Spinach & Rocket", undefined,"Pineapple & Sweetcorn"]
    delete pizzas[2];
    console.log(pizzas);
    console.log(typeof pizzas[2]);

    // output
    ['Margherita', 'Mushroom', empty, undefined, 'Pineapple & Sweetcorn']
    undefined
```

Comment: Follo [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice) link. Hope it will clear your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an oddity of the console when displaying sparse arrays.

When a normal (non-sparse) array is logged in the console, all elements will be displayed, with a comma between them.

When one of those elements contains the value `undefined`, `undefined` will be displayed.

When the array is *spare*, the array doesn't have a value at a particular index - rather, it's that the array *doesn't have that index at all*. This is an odd situation, and to distinguish this from the array containing the value `undefined`, the console will display `empty`.

That is, it was decided that it was useful to be able to distinguish

```
const arr = [1, undefined, 3]
// arr now has own properties 1 and 2 and 3
```

from

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
delete arr[1];
// arr now has own properties 1 and 3
```

In your code, the array actually contains the same values on MDN and in browsers - it's just that they have different ways of displaying nonexistent indicies.

The best way to approach this sort of thing is to never have sparse arrays - they're confusing and don't have much of a purpose in well-designed code. If you want to have a collection of keys and values, where the keys are integers but not necessarily all of them will exist in ascending order, use an object instead of an array.

```
// This code is perfectly fine:
const pizzas = {
  0: "Margherita",
  1: "Mushroom",
  2: "Spinach & Rocket"
  // ...
}
delete pizzas[1];
```

If you want an array and you want to remove an element such that the indicies shift down when an element is removed, I'd use `.filter`.

```js
const pizzas = ["Margherita", "Mushroom", "Spinach & Rocket", undefined,"Pineapple & Sweetcorn"];
const pizzasWithoutSpinach = pizzas.filter((_, i) => i !== 2);
console.log(pizzasWithoutSpinach);
```