# Why does the array still have a non-zero length after deletion?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code that outputs the length of an array, deletes it, and then outputs the new length:

```
console.log($scope.adviceList.activeAdvices.length); // *1*
$scope.adviceList.activeAdvices.splice(id,1); // *id is a parameter*
console.log($scope.adviceList.activeAdvices.length); // *0*

console.log($scope.adviceList.activeAdvices.length); // *1*
delete $scope.adviceList.activeAdvices[id];
console.log($scope.adviceList.activeAdvices.length); // *0*
console.log($scope.adviceList.activeAdvices); // *[]*
```

After the deletion, the array is correctly displayed as empty. Its length, however, is still 1.

Comment: Where are these variables declared?

Comment: See first answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript object with array, deleting does it actually remove the item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495764/javascript-object-with-array-deleting-does-it-actually-remove-the-item)

Comment: why the length is zero after you spliced id to the array?

Comment: @B.K.
the array held only that element

Comment: @B.K.: `.splice` does not only add elements, it also removes them. In this case it removes one element.

Comment: `delete` is a "lower" level operator. It directly works on the object, it doesn't "know" about the array. Using `delete` simply doesn't trigger the routine to recompute the array length.

Comment: *"delete won't actually delete the item, but rather set it to undefined"* That's incorrect. The property is removed. Try `var a = [1]; delete a[0]; console.dir(a);`

Comment: You really shouldn't edit the answer into your question. The answer already appears below the question, indicated with a green checkmark. The question should remain...the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`delete` is a "lower level" operator. It directly works on the object, it doesn't "know" about the array. Using `delete` simply doesn't trigger the routine to recompute the array length.

---

Other answers here claim that the value of the property is set to `undfined`, which is incorrect. A simple test shows that:

```
var a = [1]; 
delete a[0]; 
console.dir(a);
```

and compare to what happens if you really set the value to `undefined`:

```
var a = [1]; 
a[0] = undefined; 
console.dir(a);
```

For a more solid proof, lets have a look at the [specification](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.7):

> When the [[Delete]] internal method of *O* is called with property name *P* and the Boolean flag *Throw*, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *desc* be the result of calling the [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method of *O* with property name *P*.
> 2. If *desc* is undefined, then return **true**.
> 3. If *desc*.[[Configurable]] is **true**, then
>         a. Remove the own property with name *P* from *O*.
>         b. Return **true**.
> 4. Else if Throw, then throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 5. Return **false**.

Nowhere it is said that the value of the property is set to `undefined`.

---

The consoles of different browsers might show different representations of the array. In this particular example, you can argue whether it should be `[]` or `[undefined]`.

- `[]` (Chrome) seems to make sense because the array really doesn't have any elements, there are no properties with numeric names. However, when you access the `.length` property, you would get a `1`, which can be confusing.
  Not too long ago, Chrome used [a representation like `[undefined x 5]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10683773/218196) to indicate an array of length 5 but without elements. I think this was actually a good solution.
- `[undefined]` (Firefox) makes sense because the array is of length 1 and accessing `arr[0]` actually returns `undefined` (but so does `arr[10]`).However, `arr.hasOwnProperty(0)` would be `false` and if an array really contains the value `undefined`, how can it be distinguished from an empty array of length one solely by this representation (answer: you can't).

The bottom line is: Don't trust `console.log` too much. Rather use `console.dir` if you want an exact representation.

Comment: Why do you downvote me when that is what I wrote, the interpretation of the array object after `delete` is `[ undefined ]`.

Comment: @Antti: What makes you think I downvoted you? I didn't. As I already commented, I got confused by your console output (`[ undefined ]`) and jumped to conclusions without reading your answer thoroughly and that's why I commented. I didn't downvote however.

Comment: One thing that makes me even more confused is that MDN says that both undefined AND no property should behave the same way for forEach, but they do not behave even on Firefox

Comment: Mine says undefined, Chrome.

Comment: @johnny: Accessing a *non-existing* property will return `undefined`. That is not the same as setting the property to `undefined` though (as I demonstrated in the answer).

Comment: Node outputs `[ <1 empty item> ]`. JSON outputs `[null]`. In fact if you set and then delete an item at index 4, JSON will give you five nulls.

Answer (score 2):

It's because delete on array element set it to undefined so the length don't change. Use `splice` function instead:

```
a = [1,2,3,4];
a.splice(2,1);
console.log(a.length);
```

Comment: simple and effective

Answer (score 1):

if you want "delete" a item in array,you could

```
var a = ["a","b"];
console.log(a);  //a,b
console.log(a.length);//2
a.length = 1;//"delete" all greater than length 1 of items;
console.log(a);//a
console.log(a.length);//1
```

or

```
 var a = ["a","b"];
    console.log(a);  //a,b
    console.log(a.length);//2
    a.pop();//"delete" the last in array:"b"
    console.log(a);//a
    console.log(a.length);//1
```

or

```
 var a = ["a","b"];
    console.log(a);  //a,b
    console.log(a.length);//2
    a.shift();//"delete" the first in array:"a"
    console.log(a);//b
    console.log(a.length);//1
```

or

```
 var a = ["a","b"];
    console.log(a);  //a,b
    console.log(a.length);//2
    a.splice(1,1);//"delete" from index 1(include,first parameter),delete number is 1(second parameter)
    console.log(a);//a
    console.log(a.length);//1
```

Answer (score 0):

For my part, I redefined the length after delete:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
delete cars[1];

/// 1st option ///
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
  if(i in cars)
    document.write(cars[i] + " ");
}
/// return: BMW Saab Ford

/// 2nd option ///
cars.length--;
var realLength = cars.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new array and `push`ed elements on it to get the right length.  For example, I had this for table headers:

```
 var finalTableHeaderArray = [];

 tableHeaderArray.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    if (removeDisplayItems.indexOf(index) === -1)
        finalTableHeaderArray.push(element);
 }, self);
```

Not exactly your question, but it could help others.