# what happens when an item is deleted from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

When I deleted an item from the array "test", the keyword `delete` lead the array to become nonconsecutive. What has `delete` done?

Comment: What does it look like it did? It removed the specified item but did not change other items or the array's `.length` property. (Noting that the "undefined" displayed at the end is the return value of the last `console.log()` statement, *not* a value from the array.) An array with "holes" in it (a sparse array) can also be created with `var test = []; test[3] = "d";`.

Comment: delete is just delete, why asking?

Comment: Hi @LS.Lernord. Welcome to StakOverflow. It would be great if you could post the code, and not a screenshot of it :)

Comment: When delete item from array, item is kill.

Comment: @Super Cool Handsome Gel Boy, after delete test[1], the array's length is still 4. It looks like the test[1] item is replaced by "ghost" instead of truely delete.

Comment: @nnnnnn, i'm using chrome develope tool's console for this test, and it always output a undefined at the end of array when traverse it with "for".

Comment: Well,my question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495764/javascript-object-with-array-deleting-does-it-actually-remove-the-item

Comment: Yes, it output "undefined" for the same reason it output "undefined" after your `var` statement. As I already said, that "undefined" has *nothing* to do with the array. Regarding that question you linked to in your comment, the accepted answer is wrong: JS arrays *can* be sparse.

Comment: I'm going to hold that the "delete" just dig holes and doesn't fill them.

Answer (score -2):

Arrays in JavaScript are counted from 0. `delete test[1]` deleted the second object in the array.